# ReactJs get the state of child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to use the state of my child Component in my parent component  [in this example](https://codepen.io/meshredded/pen/aWqGBW) . what i want exactly to be able to do is this:

```
<Application onChange={(myVar)=>{console.log(myVar)}}/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're `onChange` is just a normal prop which you pass into your Application component. So if it's a function you can call it whenever you want. In this case, it makes more sense to call it when Application's `state` is updated. You can use the second parameter of `setState` function which is an optional callback function for this. But just make sure you `onChange` prop is defined and it's a function before you call it with any parameter which you want to pass.

```
class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {myVar:0};
    setInterval(()=>{
      this.setState( { myVar:this.state.myVar + 1 }, () => {
        if(this.props.onChange && typeof this.props.onChange === "function")
          this.props.onChange(this.state.myVar)
      } ); 
      }, 3000);
  }

  //.....

}
```

Updated Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gWvKxa